# Distribution of the Training Data vs Distribution of the Test/Prediction

Tags: validation, machine-learning, cross-validation, training-data

Does the Distribution represented by the training data need to reflect the distribution of the test data and the data that you predict on? Can I measure the quality of the training data by looking at the distribution of each feature and compare that distribution to the data I am predicting or testing with? Ideally the training data should be sufficiently representative of the real world distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over time, I realized that this whole issue falls under the umbrella of covariate shift which is a well studied area within machine learning. Link below or just search google for covariate shift. The concept is how to detect and ensure that your prediction data is of similar distribution with your training data. THis is in the feature space but in theory you could have label drift as well.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/07/covariate-shift-the-hidden-problem-of-real-world-data-science/

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: similar ranges would be a good idea.
Long answer: sometimes it won't be an issue (rarely) but let's examine when.

In an ideal situation, your model will capture the true phenomenon *perfectly*. Imagine the simplest case: the linear model y = x. If the training data are noiseless (or have tolerable noise). Your linear regression will naturally land on a model approximately equal to y = x. The generalization of the model will work nearly perfect even outside of the training range. If your train data were {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 9:9, 10:10}. The test point 500, will nicely map onto the function, returning 500.

In most modeling scenarios, this will almost certainly not be the case. If the training data are ample and the model is appropriately complex (and no more), you're golden.

The trouble is that few functions (and corresponding natural phenomena) -- especially when we consider nonlinear functions -- extend to data outside of the training range so cleanly. Imagine sampling office temperature against employee comfort. If you only look at temperatures from 40 deg to 60 deg. A linear function will behave brilliantly in the training data. Oddly enough, if you test on 60 to 80, the mapping will break down. Here, the issue is confidence in your claim that the data are sufficiently representative.

Now let's consider noise. Imagine that you know EXACTLY what the real world function is: a sine wave. Better still, you are told its amplitude and phase. What you don't know is its frequency. You have a really solid sampling between 1 and 100, the function you fit maps against the training data really well. Now if there is just enough noise, you might estimate the frequency incorrectly by a hair. When you test near the training range, the results aren't so bad. *Outside* of the training range, things start to get wonky. As you move further and further from the training range, the real function and the function diverge and converge based on their relative frequencies. Sometimes, the residuals are seemingly fine; sometimes they are dreadful.

There is an issue with your idea of examining the variable distributions: interaction between variables. Even if each variable is appropriately balanced in train and test, it is possible that the relationships *between* variables will differ (joint distributions). For a purely contrived example, consider you were predicting an individual's likelihood of being pregnant at any given time. In your training set, you had women aged 20 to 30 and men aged 30 to 40. In testing, you had the same percentage of men and women, but the age ranges were flipped. Independently, the variables look very nicely matched! But in your training set, you could very easily conclude, "only people under 30 get pregnant." Oddly enough, your testing set would demonstrate the exact opposite! The trouble is that your predictions are being made from a multivariate space, but the distributions you are thinking about are univariate. Considering the joint distributions of continuous variables against one another (and considering categorical variables appropriately) is, however, a good idea. Ideally, your fit model should have access to a similar range to your testing data.

Fundamentally, the question is about extrapolation from a limited training space. If the model fit in the training space generalizes, you can generalize; ultimately, it is usually safest to have a really well distributed training set to maximize the likelihood that you have captured the complexity of the underlying function.

Really interesting question! I hope the answer was somewhat insightful; I'll continue to build on it as resources come to mind! Let me know if any questions remain!

EDIT: a point made in the comments that I think should be read by future readers.
Ideally, training data should NEVER influence testing data in ANY way. That includes examining of the distributions, joint distributions etc. With sufficient data, distributions in the training data should converge on distributions in the testing data (think the mean, law of large nums). Manipulation to match distributions (like z-scoring before train/test split) fundamentally skews performance metrics in your favor. An appropriate technique for splitting train and test data would be something like stratified k fold for cross validation.

Comment: Thank you for this great detailed answer ! You are right, its really a question about how the model can generalize from the training data. The divergence between the distribution of the training data with the distribution of the test data could be a minimal measure of the potential limitation of how the model can generalize. Do you think that using techniques like KL divergence on each of the features would help provide a measure of whether the model can be trustworthy ?

Comment: Interaction between variables is indeed a problem and hence this approach of measuring variable distributions would be a necessary but not sufficient condition to state whether the model can generalize or not. Do you think that is accurate?

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, I'd appreciate if you'd accept it! @SriK

Comment: Thanks. After doing all kinds of thinking and testing with a real problem, I actually think there isnt any simple answer for this question. Measuring the distribution difference using a distance metric like KL divergence or Kolmogorov Smirnov distance of each individual feature is a very simplified means of catching glaring changes in the nature of your testing data. However, the real problem is in the joint distributions. I think the variance between the cross validation score of your training data and the CV of the test data is an indication of this issue being potentially present.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt at the answer and all your hard work, but lets capture our discussion and comments and not mark this as solved which may confuse an uninformed reader as nothing we talked about is a real actionable solution to the problem.

Comment: @SriK, I don't think there is a clean analytic solution to the problem. The reason methods like k-folds exist is for precisely this issue. Some train/test divisions will overestimate the performance metric, some will underestimate, but they should average out in the limit. If you have apriori assumptions about distributions you want to be identical between train and test, you need to be really careful that these distributions reflect the real-world distributions. Dangerous! Unless you know with the real-world distribution, matching joint distributions will over predict model performance!

Comment: @SriK, I'm curious what approach you eventually selected

Comment: I added a final solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. After going through a few months of iterating, I implemented and pushed the following solution to production and it is working quite well.

The issue here boils down to how can one reduce the training/test score variance when performing cross validation. This is important as if your variance is high, the confidence in picking the best model goes down. The more representative the test data is to the train data, the less variance you get in your test scores across the cross validation set. Stratified cross validation tackles this issue especially when there is significant class imbalance, by ensuring that the label class proportions are preserved across all test/train sets. However, this doesnt address the issue with the feature distribution.

In my case, I had a few features that were very strong predictors but also very skewed in their distribution. This caused significant variance in my test scores which made it harder to pick a model with any confidence. Essentially, the solution is to ensure that the joint distribution of the label with the feature set is maintained across test/train sets. Many ways of doing this but a very simple approach is to simply take each column bucket range (if continuous) or label (if categorical) one by one and sample from these buckets when generating the test and train sets. Note that the buckets quickly gets very sparse especially when you have a lot of categorical variables. Also, the column order in which you bucket affects the sampling output greatly. Below is a solution where I bucket the label first (same like stratified CV) and then sample 1 other feature (most important feature (called score_percentage) that is known upfront).

```
def train_test_folds(self, label_column="label"):
    # train_test is an array of tuples where each tuple is a test numpy array and train numpy array pair.
    # The final iterator would return these individual elements separately.

    n_folds = self.n_folds
    label_classes = np.unique(self.label)

    train_test = []
    fmpd_copy = self.fm.copy()
    fmpd_copy[label_column] = self.label
    fmpd_copy = fmpd_copy.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()
    fmpd_copy = fmpd_copy.sort_values("score_percentage")

    for lbl in label_classes:
        fmpd_label = fmpd_copy[fmpd_copy[label_column] == lbl]
        # Calculate the fold # using the label specific dataset
        if (fmpd_label.shape[0] < n_folds):
            raise ValueError("n_folds=%d cannot be greater than the"
                             " number of rows in each class."
                             % (fmpd_label.shape[0]))
        # let's get some variance -- shuffle within each buck
        # let's go through the data set, shuffling items in buckets of size nFolds
        s = 0
        shuffle_array = fmpd_label["index"].values
        maxS = len(shuffle_array)
        while s < maxS:
            max = min(maxS, s + n_folds) - 1
            for i in range(s, max):
                j = random.randint(i, max)
                if i < j:
                    tempI = shuffle_array[i]
                    shuffle_array[i] = shuffle_array[j]
                    shuffle_array[j] = tempI
            s = s + n_folds
#        print("shuffle s =",s," max =",max, " maxS=",maxS)
        fmpd_label["index"] = shuffle_array
        fmpd_label = fmpd_label.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()
        fmpd_label["test_set_number"] = fmpd_label.iloc[:, 0].apply(
            lambda x: x % n_folds)
        print("label ", lbl)

        for n in range(0, n_folds):
            test_set = fmpd_label[fmpd_label["test_set_number"]
                                  == n]["index"].values
            train_set = fmpd_label[fmpd_label["test_set_number"]
                                   != n]["index"].values
            print("for label ", lbl, " test size is ",
                  test_set.shape, " train size is ", train_set.shape)
            print("len of total size", len(train_test))

            if (len(train_test) != n_folds):
                # Split doesnt exist. Add it in.
                train_test.append([train_set, test_set])
            else:
                temp_arr = train_test[n]
                temp_arr[0] = np.append(temp_arr[0], train_set)
                temp_arr[1] = np.append(temp_arr[1], test_set)
                train_test[n] = [temp_arr[0], temp_arr[1]]

    return train_test
```